# handling slots in recursive components with Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have a recursive component I made that will create a form from a JSON schema.
I want to use slots, so I'll be able to add from outside some changes, when the form is generated I'm getting this error from vue:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js:588 [Vue warn]: Duplicate presence of slot
"ref-field" found in the same render tree - this will likely cause render errors.
```

This is some the main entry point for the form generator:

```html
<component-stepper
  :initData="stepperData"
>
  <template slot="non-required-step-field-ref">
    <div>HA!</div>
  </template>
</component-stepper>
```

This is the point on the form generator that the slot is being referred to:

```html
<component
  v-for="(structure, _name) in properties"
  :key="_name"
  :is="getComponentRender(structure.type)"
  :field-name="_name"
  v-bind="structure"
  :value="formData[_name]"
  style="margin-bottom: 1.5em;"
  @input="updateForm(_name, $event)"
>
  <template slot="text-field">
    <slot name="text-field"></slot>
  </template>
  <template slot="ref-field-inner">
    <slot name="ref-field"></slot>
  </template>
  <template slot="obj-field">
    <slot name="obj-field"></slot>
  </template>
</component>
```

and this is one of the endpoints that the slot should end up in:

```html
  <v-layout row>
    <v-flex
    :xs10="$slots['ref-field-inner']">
      <v-autocomplete
        :items="items"
        :value="value"
        :label="fieldName"
        :loading="loading"
        :search-input.sync="search"
        cache-items
        hide-details
        hide-no-data
        @input="$emit('input', $event)"
      />
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex
      xs2
      style="vertical-align: bottom;"
      v-if="$slots['ref-field-inner']">
      <slot name="ref-field-inner"></slot>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
```

The process does exactly what I want it to do, but what is the correct way to do it so I won't get the error?